# How to create playload in createAsyncThunk when using axios

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm starting to learn redux and there is a action creator (`createAsyncThunk`) for doing asynchronous tasks and I am trying to use `axios` within it like so

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  (authData) => {
    return axios.post("auth/token/login/", {
      email: authData.email,
      password: authData.password,
    });
  },
  {
    condition: (authData, { getState, extra }) => {
      const { auth } = getState();
      if (["fulfilled", "loading"].includes(auth.status)) {
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
);
```

this works but I get

```
index.js:1 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.config.transformRequest.0`. Value: ƒ transformRequest(data, headers) {
    normalizeHeaderName(headers, 'Accept');
    normalizeHeaderName(headers, 'Content-Type');

    if (utils.isFormData(data) || utils.isArrayBuffer(data) || utils.i… 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {type: "auth/login/fulfilled", payload: {…}, meta: {…}} 
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) 
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)
```

which is due to payload meaning I should not return axios in `payloadCreator` in the [doc](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)
they use async/await for returning the result only but in axios [doc](https://github.com/axios/axios) it mentions

> NOTE: async/await is part of ECMAScript 2017 and is not supported in Internet Explorer and older browsers, so use with caution.

so how would I approach this issue and how should I call axios in `createAsyncThunk`

Answer (score 0):

`axios.post()` returns an Axios `response` object.  You need to return the `response.data` field instead:

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async (authData) => {
    const response = axios.post("auth/token/login/", {
      email: authData.email,
      password: authData.password,
    });
    return response.data;
  },
  {
    condition: (authData, { getState, extra }) => {
      const { auth } = getState();
      if (["fulfilled", "loading"].includes(auth.status)) {
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: I need to call `async/await` this way. I don't want to do that since it's not fully supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility